# Почему сервисы мессенджеров и push уведомлений в Андроид не убиваются?

Tags: service, background, push

Я задумался недавно над одним вопросом, и пока никак не могу найти ответ на него точный.

Как работают собственно неубиваемые сервисы, например, push-уведомления. В Android, чтобы система с меньшей вероятностью убила сервис, нужно запускать его startGoreground(), тогда уведомление будет постоянно висеть вверху. Например, аудиоплееры так работают. Если же мы не хотим видеть это уведомление, мы просто стартуем сервис и в onStartCommand возвращаем флаг START_STICKY, чтобы если вдруг сервис будет убит системой, он будет восстановлен.

Собственно, вопрос в чем: Почему push-уведомления приложений всегда работают, если сервис не висит в foreground? Ну или например мессенджеры WhatsApp или Viber. Они всегда способны принять звонок в фоне, и при этом никакое notification не висит сверху.

Дело в том, что я делал как-то приложение с работой сервиса в фоне (не foreground), и там выполнялась некоторая работа, например, запрос на сервер каждые 5 сек, и иногда система его вырубала ну скажем минуты на 2, иногда на 5, причем вырубала спустя рандомное количество секунд после запуска, например даже 5 секунд. Когда же я ставил сервис foreground, все работало нормально и сервис не вырубался. 
Если бы так работал firebase, то пуши бы приходили с огромной задержкой или вообще не приходили, и звонки бы в viber не шли. 
Вот как там у них сделано?)

В инетрнетах пишут, что есть хак, когда можно запустить "неубиваемый" background сервис (при старте основного сервиса стартует второй с таким же id в foreground режиме и сразу убивается). Но неужели данный подход используют мессенджеры?)

Comment: Какая связь между сервисами и пушами? В мессенджерах пуши работают через гугл сервисы. Сервер шлет пуш, гугл сервисы его принимают и поднимают соответствующее приложение.

Comment: @post_zeev так ведь гугловские пуши тоже как то мониторят, и где они это делают, если не в сервисе? И речь не только про пуши, а ещё звонки в мессенджерах. Звонки же не через пуши работают

Comment: Пуши от гугла обрабатываются гугл сервисами. Гугл сервисы -- это системное приложение, которое имеет бОльшие права, чем обычное приложение. Оно всегда висит в фоне. Вся **сигнализация** работает через пуши (и звонки в том числе). Разработчик может сделать свою систему сигнализации, но из-за всяких доз модов это все ненадежно.

Comment: @post_zeew, что такое доз мод? 
Получается, viber, whatsapp используют firebase для звонка??